# Prove that for the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, the components sum up to $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices, positive-matrices

I had a hard time proving [fact 6 in this article](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Emec/Winter2009/RalucaRemus/Lecture1/lecture1.html):

> If $A$ is a positive column-stochastic matrix, then there is a unique eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $z = 1$ such that it has only positive entries the sum of its entries equals $1$.

Specifically, I know that by the Perron-Frobenius theorem, all entries of the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue should be positive (at least in the case above where the matrix is positive), but I had a hard time proving that the sum of these entries is 1. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You should read about Perron Frobenius Theory of stochastic matrices.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia: *Stochastic matrix*, Definition and properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix#Definition_and_properties).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I understand the Perron Frobenius Theorem but if I understand correctly, for the case above, the PF Theorem only states that the eigenvector should be positive, not the sum of the entries should be 1. Please let me know if I miss anything here.

Comment: You seem to be misreading the statement. The statement is not that the entries of *every* eigenvector add up to one. The statement is that there is a unique eigenvector whose entries add up to one. Take your favorite eigenvector and scale it so that the sum of the entries *is* $1$. (possible since they can't add up to zero). Then you need to prove uniqueness

Comment: Hi @ArturoMagidin, I'm not saying that for all the eigenvectors, the eigenvalues sum up to 1. As my title reads, I'm trying to prove that for the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 1, its components sum up to 1.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, so you mentioned that  "Take your favorite eigenvector and scale it so that the sum of the entries is 1". But isn't the statement specifically refers to THE eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue (which is one)? I don't understand why is the way of proving the statement arbitrarily taking a non-zero vector and scale it.

Comment: There isn't a single eigenvector corresponding to $1$! Talking about **the** eigenvector is the mistake. If $x$ is any eigenvector corresponding to $1$, and $a$ is **any** nonzero scalar, then $ax$ is also an eigenvector corresponding to $1$. So pick any eigenvector corresponding to $1$ with positive entries and *scale it*. **Read** the statement. It says "there [exists] a unique". It doesn't say "if $x$ is the eigenvector..."Because unless your field is the field with two elements and the eigenspace is one dimensional, there are alway more than one eigenvector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fundamentally misunderstanding the statement, and your subject line contains conceptual errors.

You keep talking about "the eigenvector corresponding to $1$", as if there were only one such vector. That's not true.

If $V$ is any vector space, $T$ is any linear operator on $V$, and $x\in V$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, then for all scalars $a$ you have $T(ax) = aT(x) = a(\lambda x) = \lambda(ax)$, so $ax$ is also an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ if $a\neq 0$. If all entries of $x$ are positive, and $a\gt 0$, then all entries of $ax$ are positive, and it is still an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.

In particular, *unless* your field is $\mathbb{F}_2$ and your eigenspace is $1$-dimensional, you will necessarily have more than one eigenvector corresponding to that eigenvalue. So, no, the statement is not talking about "THE eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue" (from the comments), because there are *multiple* (in fact, infinitely many) eigenvectors corresponding to $1$.

The statement does not say that if $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $1$ then its entries will add up to $1$. It certainly does not say that "the" eigenvector corresponding to $1$ with positive entries have that property (because there isn't any one such vector; "the" is the singular definite article and can only be used when there is a singly determined object it is being applied to). What it says is that there *exists* an eigenvector corresponding to $1$ with the desired properties, and it will be the unique such eigenvector.

You already know that the properties of $A$ guarantee the existence of a vector $x$ with all entries positive (Perron-Frobenius doesn't say "the (sic) eigenvector corresponding to $1$ satisfies this condition"; it says there is **an** eigenvector corresponding to $1$ satisfying this condition). Say $x=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. Let $k=a_1+\cdots+a_n$. Because all the $a_i$ are positive, $k\gt 0$. Let $a=\frac{1}{k}$. Then $ax$ is also an eigenvector corresponding to $1$, also has all entries positive, but now we have
$$ax = \left(\frac{a_1}{k},\ldots,\frac{a_n}{k}\right),\qquad \frac{a_1}{k}+\cdots + \frac{a_n}{k} = \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{k} = 1.$$
So $ax$ is an eigenvector of $A$, corresponding to $1$, with all entries positive which add up to $1$. That proves existence.

To prove uniqueness, the Perron-Frobenius Theorem also tells you the eigenspace of $1$ is one-dimensional, so if $v$ is any eigenvector corresponding to $1$ whose entries add up to $1$, then $v$ is a multiple of our vector $ax$. If $v=\beta(ax)$, then the entries of $v$ add up to $\beta$ (since the entries of $ax$ add up to $1$), so $\beta=1$, hence $ax=v$, as desired.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!